# What is this rectangular device on my apartment wall?

Tags: walls, interior

So on this particular wall in my apartment I have two fire detectors (one that's plugged in but seems to have some sort of internal battery and one that takes 9V batteries), a thermostat and...  this:

[image]

Any idea as to what it is? Carbon Monoxide detector? Something else?

Comment: "But where is the button?"

Comment: Does it go ding dong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like a doorbell to me.  Can't be sure though unless you pop off the case, which should come off fairly easily if you pull it straight out from the wall.

Comment: I vote doorbell also.  I'll double down and say it's a Newtone.  lol.

Comment: @shirlockhomes - Its NuTone

Comment: We don't do no fancy spelling here.  We spell words likes they sounds!